# how to put condition for date type data

Tags: php

I have table for tasks list.

how can I create condition for dates?

I want to give red color for tasks that their targerDate are in 2 days or less.

```
    $mainQuery = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `tasks `");
    while($mainIndex = mysql_fetch_array($mainQuery)) 
{
if ($mainIndex['tagertDate'] <= ???)
}
```

sql table:

```
id  int(10) 
title   varchar(250)    utf8_general_ci
targetDate  date
```

Answer (score 0):

You can Use PHP's [DateTime](http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) and [Diff function](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.diff.php) to get the desired result.

Following Function return differnce between current date and provided date in days.

```
function getDays($date) {
    $datetime1 = new DateTime($date);
    $datetime2 = new DateTime();
    $noOfDays= $datetime1->diff($datetime2);
    return $noOfDays->format('%R%a days');
}
```

Update:Use a function to compare date like this

**Here is check that Say if days returned by getDays($mainIndex['tagertDate']) is less than or eqaul to 2.**

```
if(getDays($mainIndex['tagertDate']) <= 2) {
    Make things colored here
}
```

Comment: if $mainIndex['tagertDate'] is 2015-10-26, 
Can I do if ($mainIndex['tagertDate']) - date(Y-m-d) >=2  ) ?

Comment: Actually [date](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) returns a string and [numeric operations on strings](http://php.net/language.types.string) are not same as operations on numbers,so better not to use as per u suggested.

Comment: I haven't tried yet...I'm not sure that your answer is the solution - where is the check if the targerDate are in 2 days or less?

Comment: @Roi it is there already ,check last line codes. and also i added comment at that line.